# Unable to run a selective pandas profiling for large dataset

Tags: python, pandas-profiling

I have a large dataset with 100 columns and 100000 rows and I'm trying to run a pandas profile report but it generates a very large file html file(300MB). Unable to open that file on any browser.

So I tried minimal=True but that just provides Interactions.

Can I run a selective pandas profiling report to view Interactions report only or missing _values report only

I tried this but ran into errors

`ProfileReport(df,variables=False,Interactions=True, Correlations=False, Missing_values=False, Sample=False)`

Comment: Please post the errors and your system configuration as well.

Answer (score 0):

There can be multiple possible improvements by tuning the configuration:

- Plotting interactions with 100 columns generates 100 x 100 = 10.000 plots. You can narrow this down to the ones you're interested in by specifying a target (see the documentation)
- The `ProfileReport(df,variables=False,Interactions=True, Correlations=False,  Missing_values=False, Sample=False)` is not the right syntax (please don't use capitalization, use `None` instead of False, see [this page](https://pandas-profiling.github.io/pandas-profiling/docs/master/rtd/pages/advanced_usage.html#configuration-shorthands)) .